# Newline character treated differently between Visual Studio compiler and g++

Tags: c++, g++, newline

I'm writing a C++ program that parses XML into JSON for a class and it works great when I compile in Visual Studio but behaves strangely when compiled with g++ in Linux.

With a bit of testing, I believe I have tracked the issue down into a difference in the way new lines are handled between the different compilers, here's some of the code I'm using to debug:

```
while (!fileToRead.eof()) { //Until we have reached the end of the file: ...
        cout << endl << "newloop: ";
        char c;
        fileToRead.get(c);
        cout << "read " << c << " ";

        if (c != '\n' && c != '\t') 
                cout << "is a text character.";
}
```

When I run an executable created in Visual Studio, it outputs the following for new line characters it reads:

```
newloop: read 

newloop: read 

newloop: read 

newloop: read
```

When I run it on Linux when compiled with g++, it outputs the following for new line characters it reads:

```
 is a text character.
newloop: read

 is a text character.
newloop: read

 is a text character.
newloop: read

newloop: read
```

As you can see, when compiled with g++ there are 2 problems:

- The third cout ("is a text character.") runs before the first and seconds couts ('"endl << << "newloop: "' and '"read " << c << "')
- The if statement ("if (c != '\n' && c != '\t')") runs even when c is a new line character.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Windows also puts a carriage-return character in there, right before the linefeed. It's escape is `\r`.

Comment: not the problem but also see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Steve How would *Windows* put that there? I'd say whatever piece of software (probably some text editor) he used to create that .xml file is responsible for the crappy `\r\n` newlines.

Comment: @RocketNuts Okay, if you'd like to be pedantic, *Windows* didn't put them there, but on Windows, text files have those two characters as new-line (in general).

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing the same XML file. Even if it *looks* the same in a text editor.

My guess is, the one on windows contains CRLF newlines (`\r\n` or `0x0D 0x0A`), the other only contains LF (`\n` or `0x0A`) newlines.

Make sure you have the **exact** same file on either system, and you'll get the same results.

Comment: I am using FileZilla to move the xml files from my computer to the linux server. I am not editting them after moving them, so they should be the exact same files unless they were altered by FileZilla for some reason.

Comment: @AaronT I would write your software to be tolerant of either kind of new-lines, regardless.

Comment: My guess is the opposite: he probably *did* use the exact same file, which contains `\r\n`, leading to the problem. On Windows, the input stream translates `\r\n` to `\n`, but on Linux it doesn't.  A simple solution is to modify `c != '\n' && c != '\t'`  to include checking `'\r'`. (Perhaps using `std::isspace`).

Comment: Steve and M.M were right. I added this to the if statement "&& c != '\r' and now everything seems to be working well. Thanks!